# Cannot import name 'set_array_function_like_doc' from 'numpy.core.overrides'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm unable to import packages into anaconda Jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy
ImportError: cannot import name 'set_array_function_like_doc' from 'numpy.core.overrides' (C:\Users\4523220\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py)


import pandas as pd
ImportError: cannot import name 'set_array_function_like_doc' from 'numpy.core.overrides' (C:\Users\4523220\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py)
```

This is happening after restarting Anaconda.